Cannot find module '@/assets/image.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts
I'm working on a React Native project with TypeScript, and I'm trying to import an image like this:
Cannot find module '@/assets/image.png' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

I've already checked that the image exists at the specified path. How do I resolve this error and properly handle static assets like images in a TypeScript-based project?
Any help would be appreciated!

Create a index.d.ts file in the src folder and insert this declaration.
declare module '*.png';

Restart the TS Compiler if issue persists.


Step 1: Create a declarations.d.ts file
In the root of your project (or in a src/types folder if you have one), create a file called `declarations.d.ts`.

Inside this file, add the following code to declare the module types for image assets like PNG, JPEG, etc.```

`declare module '*.png' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}`

`declare module '*.jpg' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}`

`declare module '*.jpeg' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}`

`declare module '*.svg' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
`

